# How to create Spark connection str based on configuration?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have the following config:
Databricks Runtime Version
5.5 LTS (includes Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11)

Is it a correct connection string for Spark? I've never created it before.

```
conn_str = "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.2"

spark = (
   SparkSession.builder
        .config("spark.jars.packages", connection_str)
        .config("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", False)
        .getOrCreate()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Databricks platform, then the `SparkSession` is already initialized when you started the cluster and it could be too late to install packages.  It's better to install these libraries one by one, using the Libraries tab in the created cluster - use the `Maven` coordinates part to install `org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3` and `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.2` separately.  See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html) for details.